# DistributedPubSubMediator to send past messages to new subscribers

Tags: akka, cluster-computing, publish-subscribe

I was looking into the `DistributedPubSub` of `akka`, and would like to receive messages from an `Actor` that subscribed late to see events for example in the last 10 minutes. Could not find anything like this in the API and the documentation is very scarce. Is there any functionality to the current `Meditator`, like as you would receive all the past cluster mutation events when you join in.

Comment: Did you consider using something like a `RabbitMQ`?

Comment: @BranislavLazic, I'd probably use Kafka is there's no support built into `akka`.

Comment: I used [SpinGo](https://github.com/SpinGo/op-rabbit) library for integration with RabbitMQ. But yes, I guess that Kafka will work too if you're already familiar with it and I don't like to recommend specific tools based on personal opinion. :)